# How to find out if/when a github merge request had been released as a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Being human, it looks like I know so little event about the tools I use every days.

I found a bug in rails, discovered it was already patched, and it dosent seems to be in the versions I currently require (3.2.3).

Here it is :
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5168

How would I know if a commit on master would have been packaged into a gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any one way to tell. You can take a look at the [tags](https://github.com/rails/rails/tags) for the project, and that will tell you when new versions of rails are released. Each tag is for a specific commit. If that commit happened after the patch was merged, then the patch is most likely in that version of rails.

You could also view the source of the latest gem file and see if the patch is in there:

```
gem install rails
gem unpack rails
cd rails-[VERSION]
```

Comment: Good suggestion but when I `gem unpack rails` it generate an empty directory... Unpacking other gems than rails seems to work (would explain why rails dosent show in my rubymine external libs). Using RVM. Tested on multiple machines... kinda clueless about it.

Comment: imploding and reinstalling rvm fixed my gem issues. As for the question didn't find anything else than browsing code to discover it was not yet merged into a stable branch.

Answer (score 3):

If the project has good tags (and rails does), you can use `name-rev` "which will give the commit a name based on any tag it finds pointing to one of the commit’s descendants" (from http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#finding-tagged-descendants)

For example, the commit you are looking for is [404b73bce1f9347ca05b1496db8fc64438d66bd2](https://github.com/kennyj/rails/commit/404b73bce1f9347ca05b1496db8fc64438d66bd2), so you can try:

```
$ git name-rev --tags 404b73bce1f9347ca05b1496db8fc64438d66bd2
404b73bce1f9347ca05b1496db8fc64438d66bd2 undefined
```

This tells me that (at the time of this writing) there is no tag that includes `404b73bce1f9347ca05b1496db8fc64438d66bd2`, and I'll assume that if it's not tagged, then it hasn't been released.

However, for another example, if I use a commit that I do know is in a release, it shows that it is under the v3.2.3 tag:

```
$ git name-rev --tags 45d6cd94b3ef2ec77166def41f29188445b35608
45d6cd94b3ef2ec77166def41f29188445b35608 tags/v3.2.3^0
```

For more ways to find if a commit has been released, check out http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#finding-tagged-descendants.

Answer (score 0):

In bundler you can define a gem that is not yet released, but lives on any git repo, e.g.

```
gem 'hadoop-csv', :git => 'git://github.com/apohllo/hadoop-csv.git'
```

You can also specify a branch, tag or even a commit. So this works very well in such circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but your answer didn't match the question :)

Comment: Yeah, that's right :) Maybe I should place it as a comment to the accepted question - this is just the solution for the lack of the expected mechanism in Rubygems/Github.